# trying to get footer to stick to bottom

Tags: css, html

here is my site
http://iadprint.com/services

i have tried everything to get the footer to stick to the bottom but nothing wont work other than doing a set height in css on the tag #cright but i dont want to do that since dynamic content would go in there. can anyone see what im missing or doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Stick as in position:fixed or something else?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

add to your footer css

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

If you want footer to always be at the bottom regardless of window scroll then use

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'sticky footer' trick in combination with Javascript (e.g. `jQuery.height()`)?  You could detect the new footer height and update the css accordingly.

See also this [CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

Comment: Actually, your link references this site -  http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ - which has more documentation on usage.

Comment: @Ciaran the css-tricks link is far more clear and to-the-point in my opinion